# Gradle mixed versions warning

Tags: android, gradle

My app uses API 19, I put a MapView inside of one of my layouts and added the google maps implementation. Now I'm getting a warning from gradle that I'm mixing versions.

Here is the warning:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-rc02, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 more... (Ctrl+F1)

Here are my gradle dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

The warning is showing for `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'`.

I'm unsure where to find the correct version to use for `play-services-maps` or how to resolve this issue properly. I do not want to downgrade my min version from 19.

Answer (score 3):

Add this at the end of your build.gradle (:app)

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '26.1.0'
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: @AnuMartin well, it just sets a rule for all your dependencies in that particular project that if those libraries you've added has their own particular libraries & those libraries have dependencies with the group id 'com.android.support' then they should use version '26.1.0' :)

Comment: @DarShan I had a runtime error but this solved it! thank you

Answer (score 3):

the suggestion reads:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).

this means, that you'd have to `exclude` `26.1.0` and provide `28.0.0-rc02` instead:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02"
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1") {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "support-media-compat"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
}
```

there might be further versions clashing, while fixing them works the same.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to project/.idea/libraries folder on your file system and see which libraries are different.

2.You will have to manually include these libraries with the same version in your build.gradle file.

3.Then, sync your project

In Your Case:-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02'
```

You need to add Dependency :-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//put this things in build.gradle(Project) file
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

Comment: your problem many solutions because this problem generates by the library so if any problem face so let me know.Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

You need to fallow the below steps.
1- project/.idea/libraries 
here you will see which library is different.
You can correct the different one according to your all libraries.
Then, sync your project.

Comment: You can also find the correct version of libraries  in android studio 3.0 or above version by suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Just add this lins

`implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'`

Answer (score 0):

Confronted to the same issue, I solved it by doing the following:

- Checked the sdk version for my project, in the build.gradle file, to know the version and change the libraries accordingly
- Then I had to override the libraries and change the versions that are inline with the sdk

The image attached shows the libraries I had to override:

- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable **changed to 28.0.0**
- com.android.support:support-media-compat **changed to 28.0.0**
- com.android.support:support-v4 changed **to 28.0.0**

[image: android studio project dependencies]

What I understood is that the android support, drawable and compat libraries were predefined with the 26.1.0 version and my sdk version and target was 28 so I had to change that.

My gradle runs smoothly, and have not yet experienced any problem.